# Is $\{3\}$ a subset of $(0, 3)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\{3\}$ is a subset of $(0, 3)$, true or false?

I'm inclined to say true, however my textbook is indicating that it's false because $\{3\}$ is a set and $(0,3)$ is an interval.  Perhaps I'm reading that out of context.  Am I on the right path?

Comment: Is $3 \in (0, 3) = \{x \text{ a real number} \mid 0 < x < 3\}$?

Comment: **Remember** $a\in A \iff \{a\} \subset A$

Comment: Also, what Dylan said.

Comment: The notation $(0,3)$ is a set and denotes the set $\lbrace x \vert 0 < x < 3 \rbrace$, that is all real numbers between 0 and 3, not including 0 and 3.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the insight.  This text is as clear as mud sometimes!

Comment: False: $(0,3)$ does not include $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No $3\not\in (0,3)$. Threfore, $\{3\}$ cannot be a subset of $(0,3)$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the insight. This text is as clear as mud sometimes!